# How to cut a datetime and remain the time part only

Tags: r

I have data like below:

```
2018-04-01 00:12:45.823 
2018-04-01 00:12:49.897 
2018-04-01 00:12:56.207
```

How to cut them only remain:

```
00:12:45.823
00:12:49.897
00:12:56.207
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can also use and convert back to time:

```
mytime<-"2018-04-01 00:12:45.823"
strsplit(mytime," ")[[1]][2]
#[1] "00:12:45.823"
```

Well, reading this data with `read.table` breaks it up "nicely":

```
mytime<-read.table(text="2018-04-01 00:12:45.823 
2018-04-01 00:12:49.897 
                   2018-04-01 00:12:56.207",header=F)
      V1           V2
1 2018-04-01 00:12:45.823
2 2018-04-01 00:12:49.897
3 2018-04-01 00:12:56.207
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` to match characters until one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^[^ ]+\\s+", "", df1$col)
#[1] "00:12:45.823" "00:12:49.897" "00:12:56.207"
```

Or convert to `POSIXct` and then `format` (here, there could be slight changes in accuracy of the decimals)

```
format(as.POSIXct(df1$col), "%H:%M:%OS3")
#[1] "00:12:45.822" "00:12:49.897" "00:12:56.207"
```

---

Or with `separate` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   separate(col, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep=" ") %>% 
   select(col2)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("2018-04-01 00:12:45.823", "2018-04-01 00:12:49.897", 
           "2018-04-01 00:12:56.207")
df1 <- data.frame(col = str1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)
datetimes <- c('2018-04-01 00:12:45.823', 
'2018-04-01 00:12:49.897', 
'2018-04-01 00:12:56.207')
dgt2 <- DGT %R% DGT
str_extract(datetimes, dgt2 %R% ':' %R% dgt2 %R% ':' %R% dgt2 %R% DOT %R% dgt2 %R% DGT)
```

May be more readable.
dgt2 is 2 digits to make expression shorter.

```
[1] "00:12:45.823" "00:12:49.897" "00:12:56.207"
```

The same result gives this:

```
str_extract(datetimes, digit(2,2) %R% ':' %R% digit(2,2) %R% ':' %R% digit(2,2) %R% DOT %R% digit(3,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

string a = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString();
Replace DateTime.UtcNow to your dateTime and get easily time string.